# Sign SOAP message with WS-Security

Tags: java, soap, ws-security, wsimport

I need to consume a SOAP API which requests all the messages to be signed policy "SigOnly".

I've generated the client code from the WSDL using `wsimport` and I was expecting it to generate the code for signing as well but it's not.

```java
MyWebservice service = new MyWebservice();
MyWebservicePortType port = service.getMyWebserviceSOAPportHttp();

// Build request
ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
MyRequest request = objectFactory.createMyRequest();

// Call endpoint

port.myRemoteMethod(request);
```

Is there an extra switch for the `wsimport` tool to generate code for signing or am I missing some steps in the client's code?

Answer (score 0):

WS-Security is an extension to soap, so I don't think wsimport could handle it in code generation.
Anyway you can write your handler to add ws-security headers in your soap requests.
You can add a handler to your port in this way :

```
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>();
handlerChain.add( new MyHandler() );
Binding binding = bp.getBinding();
binding.setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
```

MyHandler class must implement SOAPHandler.
This is an example of an implementation of handleMessage method of MyHandler, adding a header

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {

        SOAPEnvelope envelope = smc.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader();
        SOAPElement security = header.addChildElement("Security", "wsse",
                "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        SOAPElement usernameToken = security.addChildElement("UsernameToken", "wsse");
        SOAPElement username = usernameToken.addChildElement("Username", "wsse");
        username.addTextNode("MyUser");

    }
}
```